# How to run a signle node.js project on different ports

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I run node.js project on 2 different ports simultaneously?
e.g. domain.com:1010/ and domain.com:2020/

But the source of these 2 different ports should be the same project.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you not use `.listen()` multiple times?

Comment: Yes I have tried to run simultaneously on different ports but working only with the first port.

Comment: Not enough details. Do you want to use the same process or the same program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first idea that came to my head is passing port as argument.
With that there should be no problem to use

```
$ node app.js 1010
```

in one terminal and

```
$ node app.js 2020
```

in another.
You can get arguments passed to your program with an array

```
process.argv
```

for example `process.argv[1]` should give you port if you start your app as I did upper

Comment: Thanks for the solution and it's working! What do you think, is it not heavy for the server running 2 servers simultaneously?

Comment: Re: the load on the server - this method creates two node.js processes to run the script twice with two different ports, therefore it requires twice the resources. The answer given by @MayorMonty below only creates one node.js process and therefore requires less resources, but the single node.js process will have to listen and serve more requests. Will it be too heavy? That depends on your server hardware - I'd say probably not, unless you're trying to run it on a Raspberry Pi or something really low-power.

Comment: Exactly as @Kryten said. I would like to note that Node is one-threaded, so using this way you are getting some sort of paralleism.

Comment: @PrzemekLewandowski The best way to get parallelism with node.js using `cluster`, this solution is kind of hacky ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you have your [`http.Server`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_server) class in a variable, like so:

```
var server = http.createServer(handler);
```

you cannot call [`.listen()`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listen_handle_callback) multiple times; the subsequent calls have no effect.

But what you can do is register two `http.Server` classes with the same handler and have the `.listen()` to different ports, like:

```
var server1 = http.createServer(handler)
var server2 = http.createServer(handler)

server1.listen(3000);
server2.listen(5000);
```